# PHP: Remove empty values from array and shift values up

Tags: php, arrays, coding-efficiency

I'm trying to create a function that shifts array values up a key if the previous key is empty and one after is set. E.g. this array:

```
array (size=4)
    'row1' => string 'row1' (length=4)
    'row2' => string '' (length=0)
    'row3' => string '' (length=0)
    'row4' => string 'row4' (length=4)
```

should become this after my function call:

```
array (size=4)
    'row1' => string 'row1' (length=4)
    'row2' => string 'row4' (length=4)
    'row3' => string '' (length=0)
    'row4' => string '' (length=0)
```

I do have a working function, however, it uses a lot of if statements and I'm 100% sure that it could be done more efficiently, any ideas on how to achieve efficiently?

Thanks

Comment: Closely related question: [Array to send empty value at last and rearrange array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51302426/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try this with a big array, and hope this will help you out. The way of  question is different but your question is same as

**1. Getting empty values at end.**

**2. Non empty at starting without changing order**

**3. Without changing keys order**

If you think about any array this result come to end.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/783656)

```
<?php

$array=$tempArray=array(
    'row1' =>  'row1',
    'row2' =>  '' ,
    'row3' =>  '',
    'row6' =>  'row6' ,
    'row4' =>  'row4' ,
    'row5' =>  '',
    'row7' =>  'row7' ,
    'row8' =>  ''
);
$result=array();
$tempArray=  array_values($tempArray);
$tempArray=array_values(array_filter($tempArray));

foreach(array_keys($array) as $key_key => $key)
{
    if(!empty($tempArray[$key_key]))
    {
        $result[$key]=$tempArray[$key_key];   
    }
    else
    {
        $result[$key]="";
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [row1] => row1
    [row2] => row6
    [row3] => row4
    [row6] => row7
    [row4] => 
    [row5] => 
    [row7] => 
    [row8] => 
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in a single line, making use of `array_` functions.

```
$o = array_combine(array_keys($input), array_pad(array_filter($input), count($input), ''));
```

- `array_filter` will, by default, remove any empty values from the array
- `array_pad` will pad the array to the length of the original array, adding an empty string
- `array_keys` will get the keys of the original array
- `array_combine` will combine the keys with the values

The above would output the following:

```
array (size=4)
  'row1' => string 'row1' (length=4)
  'row2' => string 'row4' (length=4)
  'row3' => string '' (length=0)
  'row4' => string '' (length=0)
```

#### [Here's a demo](https://eval.in/783698)

Comment: This is noticeably more considered than the accepted answer.  I nearly used this page as a duplicate to close with, but for the new post I could not rely on `array_filter()` to leave `0` alone.  Oh well, this is a clean, concise oneliner.

Comment: I firstly considered this too complicated, so I went to find my own way, I started by array_filter, and realized oh wait, I need to maintain the keys as in your answer, so I am back here and go to use your solution as it's logical, thanks

Answer (score 0):

- unfortunately you did not share your code, so we cannot know what you do exactly
- also it would be helpful if you added the array as code we can run directly and do not need to edit/re-create

I would

- ignore the keys for processing the list when possible
- `unset` entries that are nor needed any longer
- iterate lists with `foreach`

apart from this you can sort lists in PHP (by value, key; asc, desc; with/without association), they have a nice [overview](http://php.net/manual/de/array.sorting.php) on that in the manual.

example steps:

```
<?php

$a['row1'] = 'row1';
$a['row2'] = '';
$a['row3'] = '';
$a['row4'] = 'row4';

print_r( $a );

arsort($a);

print_r( $a );

//get rid of double entries
$f=array_flip( $a );
//get rid of empty entries
unset($f['']);

print_r( array_flip( $f ) );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

```
 $yourarr=array('row1'=>"row1",'row2'=>"",'row3'=>"",'row4'=>"row4");
    $array1=array();
    $array2=array();
    foreach ($yourarr as $key =>$val){
    if(empty($val)){
    $array2[$key]=$val;
    }else{
    $array1[$key]=$val;
    }
    }
    $newarr=array_merge($array1,$array2);
    //<!-- Try This if you want to remove the empty indexes just put ! infront of the empty and delete the else part and to reset the row count -->

    $i=1;
    $newarr2=array();
    foreach($newarr as $key =>$val){
    $newarr2['row'.$i]=$val;
    $i++;
    }
    var_dump($newarr2);
```

**OUTUT**

```
     D:\wamp64\www\test\index.php:21:
array (size=4)
  'row1' => string 'row1' (length=4)
  'row2' => string 'row4' (length=4)
  'row3' => string '' (length=0)
  'row4' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: i have made an edit to the code  please check the output