# Array to send empty value at last and rearrange array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array.

If any array values within between becomes empty or null I want any after that empty value to be shifted within that empty array.

I used a foreach loop by unsetting an array but the problem is that if there is a 0 value the number greater then 0 shifts at second place and greater then 0 values shifts at 1st place.

I do not know how come this is happening.

Here is my code :

```
$val1     = $this->input->post('current');
$val2     = $this->input->post('graph1');
$val3     = $this->input->post('graph2');
$val4     = $this->input->post('graph3');
$val5     = $this->input->post('graph4');
$filter   = array($val1, $val2, $val3, $val4, $val5);
//array(0, '', 2, '', '')
foreach ($filter as $key => $value) { 
    if (empty($value)) { 
        unset($filter[$key]);
        $filter[] = $value;
    }
}

$filter_new = array_values($filter);
//array(2, 0, '', '', '')
```

Comment: *if any array values within between becomes empty or null I want any after that empty value to be shifted within that empty array*. Sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Please try to add a few commas, periods and line breaks. Its very hard to understand the text, let alone the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `empty(0)` returns `TRUE`, so it's normal if your `0` value pass on 2nd position.

Try this :

```
    foreach ($filter as $key => $value) { 
        if ($value == '') { 
            unset($filter[$key]);
            $filter[] = $value;
        }
    }

    $filter_new = array_values($filter);
    //array(0, 2, '', '', '')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it really worked but I was doing this $value === "" and it  was not working why is that so ?

Comment: because `===` also check type and `$value` seems to don't be a `string` type variable.